# German Umlauts in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, accents, characters, input-encodings

I have the following BibTeX source

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Lincke2008,
  author = {Rüdiger Lincke and Jonas Lundberg and Welf Löwe},
  title = {Comparing software metrics tools.},
  booktitle = {ISSTA},
  year = {2008},
  editor = {Barbara G. Ryder and Andreas Zeller},
  pages = {131-142},
  publisher = {ACM},
  added-at = {2008-08-04T00:00:00.000+0200},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2c28c4fff6d811b643940228935a20e28/dblp},
  crossref = {conf/issta/2008},
  date = {2008-08-04},
  description = {dblp},
  ee = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1390630.1390648},
  interhash = {69e9d6ded70716bc2bb9319abfbb015f},
  intrahash = {c28c4fff6d811b643940228935a20e28},
  isbn = {978-1-60558-050-0},
  keywords = {dblp},
  url = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/issta/issta2008.html#LinckeLL08}
}
```

I'm managing my BibTeX items with JabRef. Now if I want to cite this item and while generating the PDF i get the following error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8x'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.29 R�
       diger Lincke, Jonas Lundberg, and Welf L�we.
```

I think the problem is the character `ö`. How can I avoid that? I also had similar problem with the character `é`.

Comment: @StephanKolassa -- Although that question does answer the question for pdflatex, if one uses the `utf8` coding and xelatex or lualatex, the single Unicode accented character should work.  The cited question needs an updated, properly qualified answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of actually entering the `ö` and `é` characters in your source, type `\"{o}` and `\'{e}`.

Or rather: Yrjö Engeström as `{Yrj{\"o} Engestr{\"o}m}`.

Comment: in the BibTeX source or where?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - Anywhere they appear in your source. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Then i get this error: ! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8x'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 R�
       diger Lincke, Jonas Lundberg, and Welf L\"{o}we.
?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - Make sure your source files are encoded in ANSI instead of UTF-8.

Comment: @Andrew S. Arnold Thanks a lot, encoding the database in UTF-8 solved the problem

Comment: Ah, I had it backwards. Well, as long as you fixed it, that's the important thing!

Answer (score 13):

If you use utf8(x) in your tex file, ensure that your BibTeX source file is utf8 encoded as well.

You might use

- an editor supporting different encodings, opening (in latin1 or accordingly) and save it in utf8 encoding
- [recode](http://texblog.net/hypertext-help/latex-tools/recode/)
- [iconv](http://texblog.net/hypertext-help/latex-tools/iconv/)

If you don't use utf8(x) in your tex file, load inputenc with the respective option. Or convert the tex file to the same encoding as the BibTeX source and adjust the inputenc option accordingly.

To sum up, the encoding of all involved files should be the same and match the inputenc option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, encoding the database in UTF-8 solved the problem!

Comment: But BibTeX doesn't really do UTF8...

Comment: @MartinSchröder, what are the limitations? The fact that utf8 in a `.bib` file only works with a utf8-input-encoded TeX-document? Or are there other pitfalls with utf8 and BibTeX?

Comment: @maxschlepzig: How would a 7-bit program (which BibTeX is) sort UTF-8 strings? How would it generate labels etc.?

Comment: @MartinSchröder, [Sorting of UTF-8 strings as arrays of unsigned bytes will produce the same results as sorting them based on Unicode code points.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) ;) - but fair enough, using non-numeric labels would be a problem.